# Best way to merge tons of small csv files (different column size) in S3

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have tons of small csv files (about 15kb each). These csv files have different header. I want to merge them into one csv file with all columns. Eventually, this merged csv file could be more than 100GB. When merging files, if a column doesn't exist then add this column and fill in with null. I download these csv files to EMR cluster from s3, then use Spark code to merge these csv files, and also tried to use python code to merge them. From the experiments I've done, Python code works better than Spark but not idea. Does anyone have better ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for this.

You can give the location of the files you want to read from and use Spark-java (if that's what you are familiar with?) and generate one big file

```
JavaRDD<YourObjectStructureInPOJO> objectRDD = sparkSession.read().format("csv").option("header", true).option("sep","YOUR_CSV_DELIMITER").option("mode", "FAILFAST")
        .schema(getStructureTypes()).load(YOUR_PATH_TO_READ_FROM).javaRDD().map(new YourCustomFunctionToReadIntoObjects());
Dataset<Row> yourDataFrame= sparkSession.createDataFrame(objectRDD, YourObjectStructureInPOJO.class);
```

Once you read everything, you can then write into single csv file

```
yourDataFrame.coalesce(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header", true).option("sep", "YOUR_CSV_DELIMITER").csv(YOUR_S3_PATH_TO_SAVE);
```

I am not sure about python's implementation for the same, but I hope it helps you.